# NSTimeZone isDaylightSavingTimeForDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nstimezone

As a newbie to obj c I have encountered a problem with a calendar app I am working on (roughly duplicates the native app on the face of it). I was having trouble dealling with the buttons selecting wrong date (1 day previous) when in daylight saving. Having searched for a solution and found none I came up with the following code. Could an experienced coder tell me if there's a neater or more efficient way to do this. This chunk of code feels a little clunky to me. Any constructive thoughts would be appreciated.

```
- (IBAction)dateButtonPressed:(id)sender; {
NSDateComponents *offset = [NSDateComponents new];
offset.day = [self.dayButtons indexOfObject:sender];
NSDate *selectedDate = [self.calendar dateByAddingComponents:offset toDate:self.beginningDate options:0];
NSTimeZone *currentZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]; 

if ([currentZone isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:selectedDate]) {
   offset.hour = +1;
   selectedDate = [self.calendar dateByAddingComponents:offset toDate:self.beginningDate options:0];
}
self.calendarView.selectedDate = selectedDate;
NSLog(@"pressed %@",selectedDate);
}
```

Comment: Why are you worried about the timezone at all?  The conversion routines should handle it for you.

Comment: Show some more code! How are you generating `self.beginningDate` and `self.calendar`? What does the `NSLog()` print? Try logging `self.beginningDate` and `offset` as well.

Comment: beginningDate is the fisrt month on the calandar. offset produces a +1 day for non-daylight saving and +1day+1hour for daylight saving. This code means that the currentDate is a stamp of 0000hr for the date selected. Without the if statement it produces 2300:00 on the day before the selected date when selecting dates in the daylight saving band.

Comment: All in all it means I can pass selectedDate to the next view controller to display relevant data for that date. I just wondered if thewre was a better way of doing it. Hot Licks - without the isDaylightSavingTimeForDate bit, selecetdDate is the wrong date. Most of the rest of the code is derived from TimesSquare from github.

Comment: At most you might have a problem twice a year, at the savings time transition (ie, tonight).  But you shouldn't be having even that, if the timezone of the calendar is set correctly.  I suspect you have the calendar's timezone set differently from the timezone you're using for formatting the date.